# How to display order total price in opencart order mail (needed for email markup)

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to insert email markup (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/types/PriceSpecification) for OC 2+ order mails and I'm stuck on displaying the total price without currency symbol.

The problem is that OC treats all as totals (subtotal, taxes, shipping cost and final total) so I can't figure out how to extract the final total sum after all taxes, shipping costs and so on.

```
<?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</b></td>
    <td><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the code in here:

```
/catalog/model/checkout/order.php
```

which is:

```
// Order Totals
$order_total_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' ORDER BY sort_order ASC");

foreach ($order_total_query->rows as $total) {
    $data['totals'][] = array(
        'title' => $total['title'],
        'text'  => $this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
    );
}
```

simply add the value index to the array by using VQmod.
go to xml folder inside VQmod folder
create a file, name it what you want and write these lines in it:

```
<modification>
<id>Get Value Without Formatting</id>
<version>OC 2</version>
<vqmver>1.0.0</vqmver>
<author>Your Name</author>
<file name="catalog/model/checkout/order.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA['text'  => $this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            'value' => $order_info['currency_value'] ? ((float)$total['value'] * $order_info['currency_value']) : $total['value'],
            ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```